Squarespace custom css works in inspect element in browser but not in my browser
here's my site: https://manatee-dodecahedron-ap6r.squarespace.com/
I've added a bunch of css to try and change the design of the gallery element to make the font bigger.
The css i've added works in preview and inspect element but not in a full desktop browser. if you have any ideas to solve i'd be so grateful. thank you in advance.
Here's the css in question:


#sections > section.page-section.has-section-divider.gallery-section.full-bleed-section.background-width--full-bleed.section-height--medium.content-width--wide.horizontal-alignment--center.vertical-alignment--middle > div.content-wrapper {
   min-height: 825px;
}




Fixed it by adding the following style to the selector above


padding-bottom: 20px;



